# Прямая речь. Проверка задания

Tags: прямая-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои ответы: А — 4,  Б — 1,  В — 3,  Г — 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши ответы верны.

А. *Сергей рассказал **о** своём **желании** стать военным лётчиком.*

4. Чужая речь передана с помощью дополнения, выраженного **существительным с предлогом** — *...рассказал (о чём?) **о**... **желании***...

Б. ***Как отмечают специалисты***, столь высокая концентрация действующих вулканов в одном регионе планеты — явление чрезвычайно редкое.

1. Чужая речь передана с помощью **вводного предложения** — ***Как отмечают специалисты***.

В. *Олег Петрович сказал, **что** мы будем тренироваться не только в зале, но и на улице.*

3. Чужая речь передана сложноподчинённым предложением с придаточной изъяснительной частью. Это **косвенная речь**: первое предложение — главное, второе — придаточное, присоединённое союзом ***что***.

Г. ***«Никто не знает, что я здесь»***, — сказала Руфь и очаровательно улыбнулась.

2. Чужая речь передана предложением с **прямой речью**.

[**Способы передачи чужой речи**](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/311-sposobyperedachichugoyrechi.html)

Comment: Обстоятельно и доходчиво.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо большое!